# Use tweepy to notify whenever an account follows another account

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I am trying to build a bot that notifies the a user starts following a new account. Basically I want to track the accounts followed by someone realtime. I am trying to make use of tweepy python library stream api. But was not able to find the right function/api.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the library before, but the documentation mentions this method: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.get_friends

> Returns a user’s friends **ordered in which they were added** 100 at a time. If no user is specified it defaults to the authenticated user.

Comment: Yes this is really help full. But the answer I am looking for is more related to their streaming API https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streamingclient.html. I need to make it kindof automated